# Set relative position within one index level of pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I need to create a new column "event", that contains the relative position of the row within a group, after grouping by the first level of the index.

For instance, if I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
    {'userid': 'test1', 'date': datetime.date(2021, 7, 25), 'value': 100},
    {'userid': 'test1', 'date': datetime.date(2021, 7, 26), 'value': 110},
    {'userid': 'test1', 'date': datetime.date(2021, 7, 27), 'value': 120},
    {'userid': 'test1', 'date': datetime.date(2021, 7, 28), 'value': 130},
    {'userid': 'test2', 'date': datetime.date(2021, 7, 21), 'value': 90},
    {'userid': 'test2', 'date': datetime.date(2021, 7, 24), 'value': 100},
    {'userid': 'test2', 'date': datetime.date(2021, 7, 25), 'value': 110},
], index=['userid', 'date'])
```

[image]

I expect to get the following result:

[image: with event column]

Right now I am doing this:

```
for user_id, user_df in df.groupby(level='userid'):
    df.loc[user_id, 'event'] = [x for x in range(len(user_df))]
```

Is there a better (more idiomatic) way to do this?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you post a sample dataframe and your expected output from it

Comment: Sorry, I have edited to give more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby()`+`cumcount()`:

```
df['event']=df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
```

output of `df`:

```
                   value    event
userid  date        
test1   2021-07-25  100     0
        2021-07-26  110     1
        2021-07-27  120     2
        2021-07-28  130     3
test2   2021-07-21  90      0
        2021-07-24  100     1
        2021-07-25  110     2
```